# Shapefile is not able to clip raster

Tags: python, raster, shapefile, clip, jupyter-notebook

I am working on using shapefile containing various polygons to clip a raster image. The code works for some raster images, but for some raster images, blank clipped rasters are generated. Both the raster and shapefile are in same projection, yet I couldn't find way

```
data_folder = ''  #Main Directory containing subfolders and files
output_folder = ''   #Folder containing all the images(chips) of the same date.
    
#Buffering and Reprojection of SHP files and Raster Files
for path in os.listdir(data_folder):
    full_path = os.path.join(data_folder, path)
    rep_folder = full_path + '/Reprojected' #The folder containing reprojected shape files
    temp_folder = rep_folder + '/Temp'      #Temporary folder containing buffered shape files
    if os.path.exists(rep_folder):
        shutil.rmtree(rep_folder)
    os.mkdir(rep_folder)
    os.mkdir(temp_folder)
    
    def createBuffer(inputfn, outputBufferfn, bufferDist):  #Defining function to buffer the shape files
        inputds = ogr.Open(inputfn)
        inputlyr = inputds.GetLayer()
        shpdriver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
        if os.path.exists(outputBufferfn):
            shpdriver.DeleteDataSource(outputBufferfn)
        outputBufferds = shpdriver.CreateDataSource(outputBufferfn)
        bufferlyr = outputBufferds.CreateLayer(outputBufferfn, geom_type=ogr.wkbPolygon)
        featureDefn = bufferlyr.GetLayerDefn()
        
        #Create new fields in the output shp and get a list of field names for feature creation
        fieldNames = []
        for i in range(inputlyr.GetLayerDefn().GetFieldCount()):
            fieldDefn = inputlyr.GetLayerDefn().GetFieldDefn(i)
            bufferlyr.CreateField(fieldDefn)
            fieldNames.append(fieldDefn.name) 
               
        for feature in inputlyr:
            ingeom = feature.GetGeometryRef()
            geomBuffer = ingeom.Buffer(bufferDist)
            fieldVals = [] #make list of field values for feature
            for f in fieldNames: 
                fieldVals.append(feature.GetField(f))         
            outFeature = ogr.Feature(featureDefn)
            outFeature.SetGeometry(geomBuffer)
            for v, val in enumerate(fieldVals): #Set output feature attributes
                outFeature.SetField(fieldNames[v], val)
            bufferlyr.CreateFeature(outFeature)
            outFeature = None    
            
    for root,dirs,files in os.walk(full_path):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith(".shp"):
                inputfn = os.path.join(full_path, file)
                filename = pathlib.Path(inputfn).stem  #Getting the filename without extension
    
    outputBufferfn=temp_folder+'/buffered.shp'    
    bufferDist = 0.0005   #...........Buffer Distance
    
    createBuffer(inputfn, outputBufferfn, bufferDist)   #Buffer_Function
    
    #Reprojection
    shp = gpd.read_file(outputBufferfn)
    shp = shp.set_crs("EPSG:4326")
    shp.to_file(rep_folder+"/"+filename+".shp")
       
    #Delete the temporary folder
    shutil.rmtree(temp_folder)
 

#Reprojection of RASTER file
for path in os.listdir(data_folder):
    full_path = os.path.join(data_folder, path)
    rep_folder = full_path + '/Reprojected'
    
    for path in os.listdir(full_path):
        if path.endswith(".tif"):
            srcras = os.path.join(full_path, path)
            nameras = str(os.path.basename(srcras))                
            tar = rep_folder+"/"+nameras
            ras = gdal.Warp(tar,srcras, dstSRS = "EPSG:4326")
     
    
    

output_SHPs = output_folder+"/"+"Clipping_features" #Output Shape files location (Temporary)
if os.path.exists(output_SHPs):
        shutil.rmtree(output_SHPs)
os.mkdir(output_SHPs)

for path in os.listdir(data_folder):
    full_path = os.path.join(data_folder, path)
    rep_folder = full_path + '/Reprojected'
    for path in os.listdir(rep_folder):
        if path.endswith(".tif"):
            rasin = os.path.join(rep_folder, path)  
            
            #Clip Tool 
            def ClipRasterWithPolygon (rasterPath, polyPath, outPath):
                gdal.Warp(outPath, rasterPath, cutlineDSName = polyPath, format="GTiff", cropToCutline = True)
               
            #Seperating Shape File features
            def CreateClippingPolygons (inPath, field):
                driverSHP = ogr.GetDriverByName ("ESRI Shapefile")
                ds = driverSHP.Open(inPath)
                if ds is None:
                    print ('layer not open')
                lyr = ds.GetLayer()
                spatialRef = lyr.GetSpatialRef()

                for feature in lyr:
                    fieldVal = feature.GetField(field)
                    os.mkdir(output_SHPs+"/" + str(fieldVal))
                    outds = driverSHP.CreateDataSource (output_SHPs+"/"+str(fieldVal)+"/"+str(fieldVal)+"_clip.shp")
                    outlyr = outds.CreateLayer (str(fieldVal) + "/"+str(fieldVal)+"_clip.shp", srs = spatialRef, geom_type = ogr.wkbPolygon)
                    outDfn = outlyr.GetLayerDefn()
                    ingeom = feature.GetGeometryRef()
                    outFeat = ogr.Feature(outDfn)
                    outFeat.SetGeometry(ingeom)
                    outlyr.CreateFeature(outFeat) 
            
            #Clipping Raster Layer
            def ClipRaster(inPath, field):
                driverSHP = ogr.GetDriverByName ("ESRI Shapefile")
                ds = driverSHP.Open (inPath)
                if ds is None:
                    print ('Layer not found')
                lyr = ds.GetLayer()

                for feature in lyr:
                    fieldVal = feature.GetField(field)
                    ClipRasterWithPolygon(rasin, output_SHPs+"/"+str(fieldVal), output_folder+"/"+str(fieldVal)+".tif")
            print(rasin)
        
        if path.endswith(".shp"):
            shpin = os.path.join(rep_folder, path)
            print(shpin)
            
            CreateClippingPolygons(shpin,"Name") #Attribute name to be used for seperation
            ClipRaster(shpin, "Name") #Attribute name to be used for seperation
```

The algorithm of this code is:

1. Separate different polygons from the shapefile and store them separately
2. Use these shapefiles to clip the raster one by one and store the clipped rasters

Problem faced:
Few raster files are clipped properly according to its shapefile polygons. However, some raster files are not clipped and produce blank clipped images.

Comment: Isolate some clip geometry that yields blank image and run ClipRasterWith polygon just with that. If the result is empty, study the polygon geometry. Perhaps there is something special in it.

Comment: @user30184 The raster images when clipped separately through this code, yields the required clipped images. But when this code is used for a group of raster images, it seems to malfunction for some images